# Is this a correct iText design?

Tags: java, itext

I´m making some pdf reports to be used on a web app. 
I wonder if the way I´m taking to make the designs is appropriated.
This would be a screenshot of the way I´m doing the things.

[image]

As you can see, I´m using tables to position everything in the document. I think this is a pretty much similar design to HTML. But I want to know is there is a better way to get the same result I got.
This is the document without cell borders:

[image]

I could post the code if necessary. By the way, why should I spend long hours programming these kind of stuff with iText tool when I could do things faster and maybe better looking with iReport? I like iText, it´s just a question.

Sorry for my english and thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think with iText using a table like you have done is going to be the best route.  Looks good, nice job.